# "BC30311: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to String()" error trying to extract single value from array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently trying to make a program that utilizes an API to automatically send texts to people.

The data (the names and numbers) are gathered from an excel spreadsheet, they come in the form of a long string that is then placed into two arrays in visual basic using the ":" delimiter.

Now I am trying to iterate through each item of the arrays and use the names and numbers to send a text, here is my code:

```
Dim oxl As excel.application
        Dim owb As excel.workbook
        Dim osheet As Excel.worksheet
        Dim orng As excel.Range
        Dim path As String
        Dim name As String
        Dim number As String
        Dim nameArray() As String
        Dim numberArray() As String

    Dim client As Client = New Client("API CODE")


    path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)

    oxl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    owb = oxl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\SMS.xlsm")

    name = oxl.Run("getname")
    number = oxl.Run("getnomber")

    nameArray = Split(name, ":")
    numberArray = Split(number, ":")


    For i = 0 To UBound(nameArray)


        client.SendSms(originator:="TEST", body:="this is a test mr" & nameArray(i) & " hello", numbers:=numberArray(i))


    Next


    owb.Close()
    owb = Nothing

    oxl.Quit()
    oxl = Nothing
    osheet = Nothing
    orng = Nothing
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Error   BC30311 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'String()'.
```

I know the arrays are populated with the values I want and I know I have specifically defined the variables as arrays as other questions suggested but I am still getting the same error.

Could anyone possibly help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: It would be helpful to point out which line is giving the error, and include all relevant code, so this is just a guess.  You have a parameter to `client.SendSms` named `numbers` (sounds plural) and you are passing in a single element of the `numberArray` array - perhaps that parameter is expecting a string array and you are passing in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like ZendSend.io to me. If it is the problem is here:

> client.SendSms(originator:="TEST", body:="this is a test mr" & nameArray(i) & " hello", numbers:=numberArray(i))

The **numbers:=** parameter expects an array of string and you are passing in just a string. Simple solution is to write it as an array with one element:

> client.SendSms(originator:="TEST", body:="this is a test mr" & nameArray(i) & " hello", numbers:={numberArray(i)})

Comment: No problem, but Plesse accept the answer so it gets removed from the open questions